# Get the furthest date of record state on the period that state has not been updated

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I'm trying to get the the furthest date that the record remained in STATE 'I' (invalid) without being updated to 'V' valid. Here an example (DATE is order by desc) :

```
--------------------------------
ID         STATE       DATE       
--------------------------------
1          I          30/01/2017
1          I          25/01/2017 <-
1          V          20/01/2017
1          I          15/01/2017
2          I          25/01/2017
2          I          20/01/2017 <-
3          I          30/01/2017 <-
3          V          15/01/2017
3          I          10/01/2017
3          I          05/01/2017
```

Expected result :

```
--------------------------------
ID         STATE       DATE       
--------------------------------
1          I          25/01/2017
2          I          20/01/2017
3          I          30/01/2017
```

Comment: Doesn't make sense because you dates seem to be in reverse order to what you say you are trying to get. For example, "15/01/2017" would be the furthest date without being update to "V", perhaps you means the further date **since** the state was "V"? i.e. you want to know when a record changed state from "V" to "I"?

Comment: "furthest date"? Your data is ordered descending date, so are you after the latest date before an I state turned to a V state, or the earliest date an I state appeared after a V state?

Comment: What about a case where there is an I row followed by a V row with a later date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT ID,STATE ,MIN(DATE) FROM  FURTHEST  t1
WHERE STATE = 'I'
AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT *
                 FROM   FURTHEST t2
                 WHERE  state = 'V' AND 
                        t1.id = t2.id AND 
                        t1.DATE < t2.DATE)
GROUP BY ID,STATE
ORDER BY ID;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `not exists` operator to search for `I` records that aren't followed by `V` records, and then `group by` the `id` and take the maximal date:

```
SELECT   id, MAX("date")
FROM     mytable a
WHERE    state = 'I' AND
         NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                     FROM   mytable b
                     WHERE  state = 'V' AND 
                            a.id = b.id AND 
                            a."date" < b."date")
GROUP BY id
```

**Note:**
`date` is a reserved word  in Oracle SQL, so it has to be escaped - hence the usage of `"date"`.

Comment: That seems to work in my head, though perhaps you mean MIN date?

Comment: @musefan using `max` seems to fit the OP's requirement for the "furthest" date, although `min` seems to fit the actual sample data and result. If the example data is correct, you're right, and `min` should be used.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go; 01.01.1900 is an "imaginary" minimum date, used to simplify cases where there's no "V"(alid) state for certain ID.

```
SQL> WITH test (id, state, datum)
  2       AS (SELECT 1, 'I', TO_DATE ('30.01.2017', 'dd.mm.yyyy') FROM DUAL
  3           UNION
  4           SELECT 1, 'I', TO_DATE ('25.01.2017', 'dd.mm.yyyy') FROM DUAL
  5           UNION
  6           SELECT 1, 'V', TO_DATE ('20.01.2017', 'dd.mm.yyyy') FROM DUAL
  7           UNION
  8           SELECT 1, 'I', TO_DATE ('15.01.2017', 'dd.mm.yyyy') FROM DUAL
  9           UNION
 10           --
 11           SELECT 2, 'I', TO_DATE ('25.01.2017', 'dd.mm.yyyy') FROM DUAL
 12           UNION
 13           SELECT 2, 'I', TO_DATE ('20.01.2017', 'dd.mm.yyyy') FROM DUAL
 14                                                                        )
 15  SELECT id, state, datum
 16    FROM test t
 17   WHERE t.datum =
 18            (SELECT MIN (t1.datum)
 19               FROM test t1
 20              WHERE     t1.id = t.id
 21                    AND t1.state = 'I'
 22                    AND t1.datum >
 23                           (SELECT NVL (MAX (t2.datum), DATE '1900-01-01')
 24                              FROM test t2
 25                             WHERE t2.id = t.id AND t2.state = 'V'));

        ID S DATUM
---------- - ----------
         1 I 25.01.2017
         2 I 20.01.2017

SQL>
```